# How to generate graphs and charts on the fly using web2py

Tags: d3.js, graph, web2py

I am getting data after firing from Databases. I want to generate some basic graphs using this data to interpret the results. I read some posts that [Protovis](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/) is helpful in achieving this but i can't find much content about it. In ideal scenario I would like to use [d3js](http://d3js.org/) generated data driven documents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use d3.js in web2py. This works for me using this [this d3.js sample](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_10/14_div_tooltip.html) from the book, [Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345).

Add a controller, `controllers/d3js.py`

```
import random 
def histogram():
    dataset = [(random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)) for i in range(100)]
    return dict(dataset=dataset, title='D3.js Histogram')
```

Add a view `view/d3js/histogram.html` that contains your d3.js code utilising the dynamic features that are passed from the controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{=title}}</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            {{from gluon.serializers import json}}
            var dataset = {{=XML(json(dataset))}};

            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 600;
            ...

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            ...

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of graphs/charts are you trying to generate? If you're doing basic bar charts, you can generate them server-side using web2py's HTML helpers. [Here's an example of a page that does that](http://pollfix.com/user/view_poll?poll_url_string=favorite-programming-language-31&show_result=true).

Another option, if I recall correctly, is Massimo's (web2py project leader) Canvas library, which offers a matplotlib interface.

Aside from that, as you've noted, there are plenty of javascript libraries. There's a web2py [plugin for Google charts](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1721/google-charts-plugin)

Comment: I want to generate day over day revenue generation. Basically Scatter plots with line and histograms. I was thinking of using R shiny server. But it has its own cons.